# How to distinguish btw NFT and FT under the ERC1155

Tags: erc-1155

Let's say Bob has 1 token minted based on ERC1155.
How can Bob or others distinguish Bob's token btw NFT and FT?
Or is his token can be both NFT or FT?
Please correct me.

Comment: What do you mean exactly :/ ? As far i know -> when Bob call mint `_mint(account, id, amount, data)` then he needs to give an id for the NFT `id` and how many FTs 'amount`. So the NFT has an id but no owner and the FTs are grouped by that id and have owner. But anyway it may depends on the implementation (not erc1155 expert :) )

Comment: @MajdTL 
It seems that you cited Openzeppelin's source. Based on what I know, the parameters(account, id, amount) are required to input to call mint function regardless of the type of token(NFT or FT).
What I want to know is how can third party distinguish Bob's token btw NFT and FT. Because there is no additional identifier to define the type of token as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If totalSupply of the token is 1, it is non fungible. otherwise, it is fungible.

totalSupply is not built in to ERC1155 by default, but we can add it.